# .bak file on pc, to new android device

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy, miui, redmi-device

I used mobiletrans to create a backup of everything I had on my redmi phone, and now I am trying to put everything onto my Samsung Galaxy A51.

I dragged and dropped the .bak file into the phone's storage, but I can't seem to "execute" it in order to retrieve what's "inside".
I'm sorry if I look dumb, it's because I really am.

What can I do to get it all back? If there's no way, what do you suggest? Something that could probably transfer directly from a phone to another? I don't know if it's possible once one is MIUI and the other one is Android...

Thanks anyway.